# python finding point where 3d line starts to curve

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have x, y, z coordinates in 3D space, are there methods which I can use to find the point where the line starts to curve in the 3D line? Assuming that each of the x, y, z coordinates are not perfectly aligned as well - there will be some noise in each of them.  I'll be using Python, numpy for this.

This seems to be trivial in 2D, but for some reason I'm having a hard time thinking about this in 3D.

Comment: I don't know how the data is structured, but one way I would go about that is creating a vector that goes from point p_{i-1} to p_{i}, and another from p_{i} to p_{i+1}, computing their dot product and checking their angle. Can you elaborate a bit more on how it's looking like?

Comment: Do an iterative least-squares fit until the rmse goes over some threshold?

Comment: If you're careful, you might be able to get a formula that allows you to add one point at a time.

Comment: Hmm interesting. @JoãoAreias based on what you said, I can do the following: subtract x,y,z coordinates of p_{i-1} from p_{i}, then subtract x,y,z of p_{i} from p_{i+1}. Then with those 2 vectors, calculate dot product and calculate angle. Then I can calculate point with largest angle? That makes sense to me. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that there will be noise, then this will be a bit more complicated, but I think this is an idea

Comment: @JoãoAreias I believe what you mentioned could work. To combat noise, I can also just take the vectors more distant coordinates right? Thank you!

Comment: Or take a subset and do a least square regression

Comment: @JoãoAreias oh i can do least square regression in 3d?

Comment: Yes, in any number of dimensions in fact

Comment: @JoãoAreias I see. Is there a specific python function you'd recommend for computing iterative linear least squares?

Comment: Probably just use scipy

Comment: I don't see why this is trivial in 2D but non-trivial in 3D. What's your approach for 2D and why can't it be used in 3D?